# Is it possible to get not the most recents, but the oldests users tweets with rtweet package?

Tags: r, dataframe, twitter, content-length, rtweet

I`m trying to import users tweets, but i dont want the recent ones, i want to manipulate the period of the extraction. With the following example, i got the 3200 most recent tweets:

```
userstweets <- get_timeline("genericuser")
```

I`m trying to apply the function lenght() in it, in order to get a oldest period, but i`m not having success, because lenght() only assumes one argument. I tried smtg like the following, to start the extraction in the number 500 tweet, not in the 1st (most recent one):

```
userstweets <- lenght(get_timeline("genericuser"), 500:3700)
```

Is it possible to do what i want or the Twitter blocks oldest extractions?

Comment: Apparently the API only returns the 3200 most recent tweets on a standard account. There is the option to take a premium account and use `rtweet::search_fullarchive` instead. Or if the Academic Research Project Track is relevant, you can try [academictwitteR](https://github.com/cjbarrie/academictwitteR). Not sure if there are any other solutions.

Comment: @slamballais thank u very much, bro!